# Export html from org-mode: custom date format

Tags: html, org-mode

I am exporting org files to html. I am using Org-mode 7.9.3f with Emacs 24.

How can I get a custom time format in the postamble?

I tried setting the variable org-export-html-postamble-format to

```
(setq org-export-html-postamble-format 
       '(("en" "<p class=\"date\">Date: %d</p>")))
```

Then the time format looks like this: 2013-07-16T21:20+0200

I would like to have only the date: 2013-07-16, i.e %y-%m-%d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
(setq org-export-html-date-format-string "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using now version 8.0.6 of org-mode. The variable org-export-html-date-format-string does not exist any more. Instead the  org-html-metadata-timestamp-format variable has to be customized. Also in the postamble-format %T has to be used, instead of %d.